# Android Specific Gradle product flavor combinations

Tags: android, gradle

In my code I have certain templates all deriving from one code base. For each template I want to add specific dimensions. Using flavor dimensions and product flavors I have reached this code:

```
flavorDimensions "template", "color"

productFlavors {

    templateA {
        applicationId "com.templatea"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "template"
    }


    templateB {
        applicationId "com.templateb"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "template"
    }

    templateC {
        applicationId "com.templatec"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "template"

    }

    blue {
        applicationId "com.blue"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "color"
    }

    green {
        applicationId "com.green"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "color"
    }

    orange {
        applicationId "com.orange"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "color"
    }
```

Which gives the result (I have ignored the buildtypes):

> templateABlue
>
> templateAGreen
>
> templateAOrange
>
> templateBBlue
>       templateBGreen
>
> templateBOrange   templateCBlue
>
> templateCGreen
>
> templateCOrange

Of course this is the expected behaviour but I would like to achieve something like this:

> templateA
>
> templateBBlue
>
> templateBOrange
>
> templateC
>
> templateCGreen

Thus each template derives from one main code base and each template can have different variants deriving from their code base. Is there a way to specify which flavor dimension combinations can be used or a way to exclude the combinations I don't want? Just to be clear, each template can function without specifying a color.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use gradle `variantFilter` to exclude some configurations

For example:

```
productFlavors {

    templateB {
        applicationId "com.templateb"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "template"
    }

    templateC {
        applicationId "com.templatec"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "template"

    }

    blue {
        applicationId "com.blue"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        flavorDimension "color"
    }
}

android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if(variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('templateC')
            && variant.getFlavors().get(1).name.equals('blue')) {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: does this also works like `initWith()` inside `buildType` block? @vincent-nock