# Gradle - inherit product flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I have 3 product flavors excluding the `main` one:

```
productFlavors {
    xxx {
        applicationId 'com.xxx'
    }
    yyy {
        applicationId 'com.yyy'
    }
    zzz {
        applicationId 'com.zzz'
    }
}
```

As I understand it, these product flavors inherit `main`'s resources and it looks something like this:

```
        +------->xxx
        |           
main----+------->yyy
        |           
        +------->zzz
```

So when I build `xxx`, Gradle bundles stuff from `src/main` and from `src/xxx` folders.

Now, I need it to look like this:

```
        +------->xxx           
        |                      
main----+------->yyy------->zzz
```

In other words, I want `zzz` to use `yyy`'s resources as well as `main`'s. Can Gradle do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a product flavor be a child of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022249/have-a-product-flavor-be-a-child-of-another)

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41903586/746347

Answer (score 5):

It may depends on what exactly you want to "override" in zzz.
In my project I need productFlavor inheritance too. But I needed override manifest only. I created directory for zzz with custom AndroidManifest.xml and changed other zzz src paths to yyy in build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    zzz.java.srcDirs = ['src/yyy/java']
    zzz.res.srcDirs = ['src/yyy/res']
    ...
    ...
}

productFlavors {
   xxx {}
   yyy {}
   zzz {}
}
```

P.S. Created a feature request for this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183350

Answer (score 3):

I have answered this [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168499/3211512). I will just copy and paste my answer here, hoping it will be helpful to you.

I was looking for a similar thing in gradle and found [Multi-flavor variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants). I have an app that should have versions A and B, and each version has dev and pro environments, so I ended up with this in my gradle:

```
flavorDimensions 'app', 'environment'

productFlavors {
    versionA {
        flavorDimension 'app'
    }
    versionB {
        flavorDimension 'app'
    }
    pre {
        flavorDimension 'environment'
    }
    pro {
        flavorDimension 'environment'
    }
}
```

And in my build variants I have versionAPreDebug, versionAPreRelease, versionBPreDebug, versionBPreRelease, etc. I think what you need is something like that.