# Android gradle: Sharing dependencies between product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-productflavors, gradle-dependencies

I have 3 product flavors (flavor1, flavor2, flavor3) in my app. flavor1 and flavor2 share some of the dependencies related to ads.

Is there a way to bundle the ad related dependencies to a gradle dimension or configuration and add that to flavor1 and flavor2 without duplicating the compileFlavor1 and compileFlavor2 lines in my build.gradle?

This is part of my current gradle. This works. But, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this? So, I don't have to repeat the ad dependencies for each flavor.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
        flavor2 {}
        flavor3 {}
    }

    sourceSets {
       main {}
       flavor1.java.srcDir 'common/ads/java'     <--- shared sourceSet
       flavor2.java.srcDir 'common/ads/java'
       flavor3.java.srcDir 'common/no_ads/java'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'dependency1'
    compile 'dependency2'

    compileFlavor1 'dependency3'   <----- Same list
    compileFlavor1 'dependency4'
    compileFlavor1 'dependency5'

    compileFlavor2 'dependency3'   <------ Same list
    compileFlavor2 'dependency4'
    compileFlavor2 'dependency5
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution for sharing dependencies between flavors (updated for `implementation` which has now replaced `compile`):

Since `implementation`, `flavor1Implementation`, `flavor2Implementation`, etc. are all in fact themselves [Configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html) you can actually apply an inheritance relationship between these steps in the build process.

Therefore in this case you can specify your shared dependencies, and dependencies for `flavor1` only:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'dependency1'
    implementation 'dependency2'

    flavor1Implementation 'dependency3'
    flavor1Implementation 'dependency4'
    flavor1Implementation 'dependency5'
}
```

...And then simply allow `flavor2Implementation` to inherit from `flavor1Implementation`:

```
configurations.flavor2Implementation.extendsFrom(flavor1Implementation)
```

This can also be used to define more complex relationships between flavors, and multiple inheritance is supported, e.g:

```
configurations {
    flavor3Implementation.extendsFrom(
            flavor1Implementation,
            flavor2Implementation
    )
}
```

(Finally, just a note that sharing **code** between flavors should be continued to be handled with `sourceSets` as per the original question.)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without actually explaining what's wrong with this solution...  (which we've been using for ~1yr now and works perfectly fine for us)

Answer (score 2):

This is what we did to share directories between flavors:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
    production {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/shared/java']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/shared/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/shared/assets']
    }
    logger {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/shared/java', 'src/mock/java']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/shared/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/shared/assets']
    }
    nowav {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/nowav/java', 'src/mock/java']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/nowav/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/nowav/assets']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christine. I'm already doing this with (Sharing folders between flavors). But, my question was about sharing external dependencies between flavors (please check the dependencies block from my question).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a neat way to do this (flavor inheritance is not an option for me), so I wrote a little utility for it.

#### Utility

Simply add these functions before your `dependencies` block:

```
/** Adds [dependency] as a dependency for the flavor [flavor] */
dependencies.ext.flavorImplementation = { flavor, dependency ->
    def cmd = "${flavor}Implementation"
    dependencies.add(cmd, dependency)
}

/** Adds [dependency] as a dependency for every flavor in [flavors] */
dependencies.ext.flavorsImplementation = { flavors, dependency ->
    flavors.each { dependencies.flavorImplementation(it, dependency) }
}
```

#### Usage

You use the utility like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    def myFlavors = ["flavor1", "flavor2", "flavor3"]
    flavorsImplementation(myFlavors, "com.example.test:test:1.0.0")
    flavorsImplementation(myFlavors, project(':local'))
    ...
}
```

#### How it works

The key to this utility is gradle's `dependencies.add` API, which takes 2 parameters:

1. The type of dependency, for example `implementation`, `api`, `flavor1Implementation`. This can be a string, which allows us to use string manipulation to dynamically create this value.
2. The dependency itself, for example `"com.example.test:test:1.0.0"`, `project(':local')`.

Using this API, you can add dependencies dynamically, with quite a lot of flexibility!