# Gradle: How to define common dependency for multiple flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

My app has 3 flavors (`free`, `paid`, `special`) and there's a dependency `LIB_1` need only for `free` flavor and other dependency `LIB_2` needed for both `paid` and `special` flavors.

So, my question is how to define these dependencies in `build.gradle` file?

Currently, i define them like this:

```
dependencies {
    freeImplementation 'LIB_1'
    paidImplementation 'LIB_2'
    specialImplementation 'LIB_2'
}
```

Is there a better way to define them instead of duplicating the same dependency for different flavors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the documentation of [android gradle dependency management](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-configurations), this is the only way of declaring flavor-specific dependencies.

If you are in a multi-modular project (and you don't want to repeat those lines in each submodule), you can also define these dependencies using the `subproject` block in the build.gradle of the root project:

```
subprojects {
    //all subprojects` config
}
//or
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'sample'}) {
    // subprojects that their name is not "sample"
}
```

Comment: If i understood you right, so i have to duplicate the dependency for each flavor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to avoid duplicating the dependency across flavors, as I describe in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75083956/6007104

#### Utility

Simply add these functions before your `dependencies` block:

```
/** Adds [dependency] as a dependency for the flavor [flavor] */
dependencies.ext.flavorImplementation = { flavor, dependency ->
    def cmd = "${flavor}Implementation"
    dependencies.add(cmd, dependency)
}

/** Adds [dependency] as a dependency for every flavor in [flavors] */
dependencies.ext.flavorsImplementation = { flavors, dependency ->
    flavors.each { dependencies.flavorImplementation(it, dependency) }
}
```

#### Usage

You use the utility like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    def myFlavors = ["flavor1", "flavor2", "flavor3"]
    flavorsImplementation(myFlavors, "com.example.test:test:1.0.0")
    flavorsImplementation(myFlavors, project(':local'))
    ...
}
```

#### How it works

The key to this utility is gradle's `dependencies.add` API, which takes 2 parameters:

1. The type of dependency, for example `implementation`, `api`, `flavor1Implementation`. This can be a string, which allows us to use string manipulation to dynamically create this value.
2. The dependency itself, for example `"com.example.test:test:1.0.0"`, `project(':local')`.

Using this API, you can add dependencies dynamically, with quite a lot of flexibility!